# wordpress custom field problem

Tags: wordpress

for some reason my wordpress blogs changes the custom field of my post.

When I create my post I use the custom field "description" after a few weeks or months all the descriptions are gone and when I check the database all the description were changed to _aioseop_description

I asked for support on wordpress without any luck..
I'm tired of changning this manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this should clear it up a bit

http://semperfiwebdesign.com/forum/all-in-one-seo-pack-troubleshooting/no-more-custom-fields/